Are there any hints about what ??? does in Grand Poo World 3?
In Grand Poo World 3, if you clear enough exits, then in the Secret Grove you can take an exit blocked by a box that says “???.” If you do, then

 a secret level becomes accessible on the overworld. Its location is unmarked.

Are there any indications within the game about what effect taking this exit has? And, along those lines…

 are there any hints as to where the secret level is?

Thanks!
